# ggnetwork graph does not accurately plot values to colour nodes

Tags: r, ggplot2, networking, graph, ggnetwork

I am trying to make a graph with ggplot2 and ggnetwork. I have a two dimensional lattice grid, an adjacency matrix, and I want to illustrate certain values by colour coding.

Unfortunately i can either get the network going, or the accurate colour coding, but not both at the same time.

Here is my code and sample data to reproduce my problem:

```
library(network)
library(ggnetwork)
library(ggplot2)


#SAMPLE DATA
adj_matrix <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
                       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), nrow = 9, ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE)

grid_coords <- matrix(NA, nrow=3 * 3, ncol=2)
cell_size <- 1
origin_x <- 1
origin_y <- 1
k <- 1
for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    x <- (j-1) * cell_size + origin_x
    y <- (i-1) * cell_size + origin_y
    grid_coords[k,] <- c(x, y)
    k <- k + 1
  }
}

R <- c(1.0000000, 0.5723928, 0.1447857, 1.4276072, 1.0000000, 0.5723928, 1.8552143, 1.4276072, 1.0000000)


#GENERATING GRAPH
gra <- network.initialize(nrow(grid_coords), directed=F)
gra <- network.adjacency(adj_matrix, gra)
n <- ggnetwork(gra, layout=grid_coords, arrow.gap=0)

r_i <- data.frame(R=R, X=n$x[1:nrow(grid_coords)], Y=n$y[1:nrow(grid_coords)], xend=rep(0, nrow(grid_coords)), yend=rep(0, nrow(grid_coords)))

ggplot(n, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges(color = "grey80") +
  geom_point(size=5, col="grey80") +
  geom_point(size=3.5, col="white") +
  geom_point(dat=r_i, aes(x=X, y=Y, color = R), size=3.5) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="steelblue3", high='firebrick3', name=expression(bold(R)[ix]), limit=c(min(R),max(R)), na.value = "white") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

The code above will create the network, but won't apply the correct colouring to the nodes.

[image]

However, by hashing out one line the colouring issue can be solved, but the network connecting the nodes is not generated.

```
gra <- network.initialize(nrow(grid_coords), directed=F)
#gra <- network.adjacency(adj_matrix, gra)
n <- ggnetwork(gra, layout=grid_coords, arrow.gap=0)

r_i <- data.frame(R=R, X=n$x[1:nrow(grid_coords)], Y=n$y[1:nrow(grid_coords)], xend=rep(0, nrow(grid_coords)), yend=rep(0, nrow(grid_coords)))

ggplot(n, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges(color = "grey80") +
  geom_point(size=5, col="grey80") +
  geom_point(size=3.5, col="white") +
  geom_point(dat=r_i, aes(x=X, y=Y, color = R), size=3.5) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="steelblue3", high='firebrick3', name=expression(bold(R)[ix]), limit=c(min(R),max(R)), na.value = "white") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Here is the figure with the correct colouring:
[image]

I think it might have to do with something about the synchronisation of the nodes, but havent been able to crack it so far.

Thanks for considering this problem :)

EDIT:
After Allan's solution to my original question i am wondering if there is a way to create a function which synchs up all possible node networks. Heres the sample data for a triangle:
Thanks again:)

```
#SAMPLE DATA OF NOT SYMMETRICAL LATTICE


adj_matrix2 <- matrix(c( 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 1, 0,
                        1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1, 1, 1,
                        0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0, 0, 1,
                        0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0, 0, 0,
                        0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0, 0, 1,
                        0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1, 0, 1,
                        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1, 0, 1,
                        0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0, 1, 1,
                        1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1, 0, 1,
                        0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1, 1, 0), nrow = 10, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

Xchords <- c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,3,2,3)
Ychords <- c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,1,1,2)

grid_coords2 <- (cbind(Xchords, Ychords))


R2 <- c(2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551,  2.057551, 10.517957 )
```

And here is the image with incorrect colouring:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is nothing to do with your plotting code - you simply haven't defined the node data frame correctly (examine the x and y co-ordinates of `r_i`).

If you do:

```r
r_i <- data.frame(R = R, 
                  X = rep(sort(unique(n$x)), 3),
                  Y = rep(sort(unique(n$y)), each = 3))
```

And plot with

```
ggplot(n, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges(color = "grey80") +
  geom_point(size = 5, color = "grey80") +
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y, color = R), data = r_i,  
             size = 3.5, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "steelblue3", high = 'firebrick3', 
                        name = expression(bold(R)[ix])) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title       = element_blank(),
        axis.text        = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks       = element_blank())
```

You get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Allan, Yes you are right about the node data frame! Do you know of a method to correctly assign it for any network, not just a lattice? I have added another sample dataset of a triangle at the end of the original question.